# Python cant get json value

Tags: python

I am trying to print the "Yes" that corresponds with Verified. But I can't seem to find out how to get the string yes.

The code I tried is below (Does not work):

```
data = {"addresses":[{"number":6,"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000":"BURN","Verified":"Yes","Type":"Address"},{"0x1010101010101010101010101010101010101010":"Facebook","Verified":"Yes","Type":"Address"}]}

print(data["addresses"]("number"))
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(data["addresses"]("number"))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

```
data = {"addresses":[{"number":6,"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000":"BURN","Verified":"Yes","Type":"Address"},{"0x1010101010101010101010101010101010101010":"example","Verified":"Yes","Type":"Address"}]}


print(data["addresses"])
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `print(data["addresses"][0]["number"])`

Comment: Why is the title talking about JSON? There's no JSON here at all.

Comment: I put json because I am using an api that returns JSON. Since I did not want to expose the api key I put "{"addresses":[{"number":6,"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000":"BURN","Verified":"Yes","Type":"Address"},{"0x1010101010101010101010101010101010101010":"example","Verified":"Yes","Type":"Address"}]}". Hope you now understand why I put JSON in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use three indices to display “Yes” corresponding to a Verified.
First index - key in outer dict, second index - 0th element in the inner list, third index - key in the dict within the list

```
print(data["addresses"][0]["Verified"]) # Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check what you are missing is to analyze how you have structured the data. In your case you have a dictionary with a key as a string and value as a list of dictionaries. If you understand this you will easily get the data needed.

In your case, you can access data using following code:

```
x = 0 # or 1
print(data["addresses"][x]["Verified"])
```

You can also add this in a try block to establish error handling

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple addresses you can use:

```py
for item in data["addresses"]:
    print(item["Verified"])
```